# Problem with selenium, closing the main window when opening the popup. How get href from this link?

Tags: javascript, python, html, python-3.x, selenium

My problem is that when you click on the link, a pop-up window opens, but when working with selenium, it opens, but closes the main window. I open the link using `.click()`

Here's the html:

```
<a class="do do-task btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-block" href="javascript:;"
 data-task-id="13054765" data-do-class="do-task" 
data-getcomment-href="/tasks/getcomment/" data-check-count="0" 
data-max-check-count="2" data-point-text="10 points">
<i class="far FA-star"></I> 10 points</a>
```

Function for click:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')


def click_tasks():
    tasks = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('btn-block')[7:]
    print(tasks[0].text)
    tasks[0].click()
```

You can find out the `href`, but I don't know how.

Help me find out how to get `href` or make the main window not close when you open the pop-up window. I will be grateful.

Comment: Please check the driver configuration, also put the source code.

Comment: there's probably an event listener on the body that processes the click, but hard to say without seeing the markup and scripts on the page.  The href won't be of much use.

Comment: I don't know much about this, but can I get a link from the handler? Or is it better to use pyautogui?

Comment: if the pop-up window url is what you want, you can get the url from the location bar (or driver.current_url after switching the driver to that window), or possibly from the script itself.  (the script may take a var from server in a callback though...)

Comment: do you know why the main window closes when you open the pop-up window?

Comment: I'd suspect something in your code that calls the webdriver's close method...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've initialised a driver like driver = webdriver.Chrome(), one way of getting the `href` based on the `html` you posted is:

```
your_href=driver.find_element_by_class_name('do do-task btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-block').get_property('href')
```

Comment: This didn't help, since in href=javascript:;
Using your code as a link I get "javascript:;" or "about: blank"
And I need a direct link. If you do not click through selenium, the pop-up window opens correctly and the main thing is not closed

Comment: Could it be you're performing the actions too fast? In which case you could try a WebDriverWait:
WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.<<identify the popup here>>))).click()

Comment: These imports are required before using WebDriverWait:
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC